# XMLHttpRequest with Django -> GET, ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

My method in views.py try get `product_slug` because he need `product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)` and add this product in the cart. U try use `XMLHttpRequest` with `JS` but have error 500.What I'am doing wrong?

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^cart/create/$', views.cart_create, name='cart_create'),
```

**views.py**

```
def cart_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product_slug = request.GET.get('product_slug')
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
    cart.add(product=product)

    return JsonResponse({'200':'OK'})
```

**product_list.html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_to_cart" data-slug="{{ product.slug }}">Add</a>
```

**base.html**

```
var add_to_cart = document.getElementsByClassName('add_to_cart');

for(var i = 0; i < add_to_cart.length; i++) {
    product_slug = add_to_cart[i].getAttribute('data-slug')

    add_to_cart[i].onclick = function() {
        loadA(product_slug)
    }
}

function loadA(product_slug) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    url = "{% url 'cart:cart_create' %}" + product_slug
    xhr.open('GET', url);

    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        console.log('no')
    } else {
        console.log('ye')
    }
}
```

In `console.log` output `no` and error `(Internal Server Error)`. Help me, please.

I try rewrite this code with clean `javascript/XMLHttp` > without `jQuery/Ajax`

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function() {
    product_slug = $(this).attr("data-slug")
    data = {
        product_slug: product_slug,
    },

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'cart:cart_create' %}",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".cart_score").empty().append(data.cart_length + " товаров " + data.cart_total + " &#8381;")
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: 500 most likely means an exception on the server side - that is, a Python error. Look at your Python terminal to see the error details

Comment: if the request is reaching your view `cart_create` then it is raising an exception, so you should look at your django console for the error trace.

Comment: I fix it! error because in url need `url = "/cart/create/?product_slug=" + product_slug`